# How do I identify which minifig is in a blind bag for The Muppets series of figures?

Tags: minifigure-identification, collectable-minifigures

How do I identify which minifig is in a blind bag for The Muppets series of figures?

I would like to know what is the best way to know which minifig is in the bag.

Comment: A better format for this, and more likely to keep it from being flagged to be closed, might be to pose the initial question something like "How do I identify which minifig is in a blind bag for The Muppets series of figures?" and then answering your own question with the relevant information. Possibly flagging it as a community answer to allow others to update the answer as more information is available.

As it sits right now, this doesn't quite fit the format for this site and is at risk to be at least downvoted, if not removed.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is an Answer rather than a Question. The content of this post is valuable, but it has to be an provided as an answer to some sort of question. I would also like to note that it is perfectly fine to have a question answered by the same person as long as the question (and answer) fit the scope of Brick.SE

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. Changed the format, hopefully with better fit to Brick.se

Comment: @Saariko Thanks for sharing and for taking the time to edit your post. Welcome to Bricks.SE!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I did, I went ahead and purchased a small digital scale, with .01 grams of precision.
I weighed the bags and identified them. Here are the results:

Most have unique enough weight. For the ones that are close, you can feel one of the items within the bag.

| Minifigurine Character | Weight (g) | Feel for |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dr. Bunsen Honeydew | 9.65 |  |
| Kermit the Frog | 9.85 |  |
| Gonzo | 9.96 |  |
| Beaker | 10.05 |  |
| Janice | 10.73 |  |
| Waldorf | 10.88 |  |
| Fozzie Bear | 11.22 | [Mic stand](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=coltm-7) |
| Statler | 11.24 | [Laptop](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=coltm-10) |
| Swedish Chef | 11.57 |  |
| Miss Piggy | 12.06 |  |
| Rowlf the Dog | 12.55 |  |
| Animal | 14.18 |  |